# Showing measure of a finite intersection is positive and a best possible bound

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose that $E_1 \cdots E_n \subset \left]0,1\right[$ are Lebesgue measurable sets and suppose that $\sum_{k=1}^n m(E_k)>n-1$. Show that $m\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^n E_k \right) > 0$. Show that the bound $n-1$ is best possible.

Here is what I managed to do: Assume for a contradiction that $m\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^n E_k\right)=0$, then
\begin{align}
    m\left(\left]0,1\right[\setminus \bigcap_{k=1}^n E_k\right)=m \left(\left]0,1\right[ \cap \left[\bigcap_{k=1}^n E_k \right]^c \right) & \le \sum_{k=1}^n m\left(\left]0,1\right[\setminus E_k \right)=n-\sum_{k=1}^n m(E_k) \nonumber 
\end{align}
Then we have
\begin{align}
    m\left(\left]0,1\right[\setminus \bigcap_{k=1}^n E_k \right) = 1 \le n-\sum_{k=1}^n m(E_k) \implies \sum_{k=1}^n m(E_k) \le n-1 \nonumber
\end{align}
Which is a contradictions and thus $m \left(\bigcap_{k=1}^n E_k \right)>0$.

> But how do I show that the bound on the sum which is $(n-1)$, is the best possible bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write this statement as follows: $m(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}E_i)=0$ implies $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} m(E_i) \leq n-1$. If $n-1$ is not the best bound then there exists $t <n-1$ such that $m(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}E_i)=0$ implies $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} m(E_i) \leq t$. To get a contradiction to this take $E_i=(0, \frac  s n), 1\leq i \leq {n-1}$  and $E_n=(\frac s n, 1)$ where $s=\frac {n(t-1)} {n-2}$.

Comment: But how do we get the contradiction exactly?

Comment: @user440024 $m(\cap E_i)=0$ because $\cap E_i$ is empty. But $\sum m(E_i)>t$. (This only requires a minor calculation, so I am leaving it to you). You have to check that $(n-1) \frac s n+1-\frac  s n >t$ for the given value of $s$.